# Tikz, Lua, forget semicolon problem

Tags: tikz-pgf, luatex, luacode

In this M(n)WE, there in a loss of a semicolon.

The `tex.print` part gives the good character chain it used directly in the new command, but as I want to use it in an external `\draw`, tikz claims for a semicolon that at put where it should be.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{tikz,xparse} 
\usetikzlibrary{quotes,through,calc,intersections,backgrounds}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}

\luadirect{require "LTG_Droites"}

\NewDocumentCommand{\Dt}{%
    O{1.2,1.2}  % extention
    m           % nom de la droite
    }{%
    \directlua{Draw_Droite(\luastring{#2},#1)}
    % the following works in tikzpicture
    % but want just the coordinate part
    %\draw \directlua{Draw_Droite(\luastring{#2},#1)} ;
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
% doesn't work
%\draw \Dt{d1} ;
\end{tikzpicture}

 \Dt{d1} ;

\end{document}
```

And the `LTG_Droites.lua`

```
-- #### Draw_Droite
-- #### 
-- #### Renvoie (A)--(B) + extention

function Draw_Droite ( d , extA , extB )
    local A = "(0,0)"
    local B = "(1,1)"
    tex.print("($"..A.."!"..extA.."!"..B.."$)--($"..B.."!"..extB.."!"..A.."$)")
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need the code after `\draw` to *expand* to tikz syntax:

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{tikz,xparse} 
\usetikzlibrary{quotes,through,calc,intersections,backgrounds}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}

\luadirect{require "LTG_Droites"}

\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\xDt}{%
    O{1.2,1.2}  % extention
    m           % nom de la droite
    }{%
    \directlua{Draw_Droite(\luastring{#2},#1)}%
    % the following works in tikzpicture
    % but want just the coordinate part
    %\draw \directlua{Draw_Droite(\luastring{#2},#1)} ;
}

%force full expansion of \Dt in two  expansion steps.
\newcommand\Dt{\romannumeral`\^^@\xDt}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
% doesn't work
\draw \Dt{d1} ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\Dt{d1} ;

\end{document}
```

Comment: What is `\RequirePackage{luatex85}` for ? I don't understand.

Comment: @Tarass luatex0.85+ (in particular luatex 0.95 in texlive 2016 which I'm using) is massively incompatible with previous luatex and with pdftex, luatex85 package (which you should have already in an up to date texlive or miktex) emulates many of the commands that have been removed (so pgf still works)

Comment: I never used such packages. Your answer works without. What does it bring in this cases?

Comment: @Tarass you presumably have an older version of luatex. If you update luatex (before the pgf maintainers update pgf) all your documents using tikz code will stop working unless you load that compatibility package. in older luatex (such as 0.80 in texlive 2015 the package does nothing)

Comment: I use texlive 2015 uptodate. When I make an update I update all installed packages. The versions of tikz and lua latex will be coherent and will work together, won't they?

Comment: @Tarass texlive 2015 yes, texlive 2016 no, not yet not unless you use the compatibility package (I expect it will be updated in the next week or so, texlive 2016 is still in test phase)

Comment: OK I understand then the use of a compatibility package during the test time. Thank you for your explanations and for the answer.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I try to compile your code (under texlive 2017) and get this error `Latex Error: ./lua_tikz_ex_1.tex:26 Package tikz Error: Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?.`

Comment: @AlainMatthes hmm so do I. It must have worked back then, I am of course a complete fraud at tikz but I'll see if I can see what the issue is.

Comment: @AlainMatthes This is due to a change in expl3 a year ago, we are looking at exactly the issue is...

Comment: @AlainMatthes https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42238962#42238962: I guess one of us should ask a question on this (I now know what is going on)

Comment: @AlainMatthes I have updated the answer to work with current tikz/expl3

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks! very useful because I try  to make a new version of tkz-euclide with L3 and lua.